# Check if scipy sparse matrix entry exists

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I initialize an empty sparse matrix using

```
S = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((n,n),dtype=int)
```

As expected `print S` doesn't show anything, since nothing has been assigned.
Yet if I test:

```
print S[0,0]==0
```

I receive `true`.

Is there a way to test if a value has been set before? E.g. along the lines of `ifempty`?

Comment: The point of a sparse matrix is that most of the values are *0*.  There is no "unassigned" value.

Comment: That is not quite true. If I assign a explicit 0 to a entry, i.e. `S[0,0]=0` and I call `print S`, I get the value returned: `(0, 0) 0`. So somehow it can be distinguished between unassigned and 0.

Comment: Sure, but you won't be able to tell from accessing S[0,0].  You'd have to dig into the underlying representation.  So it will depend on the format of the sparse matrix (e.g. CSR, DOK, COO, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for stored values with

```
def get_items(s):
    s_coo = s.tocoo()
    return set(zip(s_coo.row, s_coo.col))
```

Demo:

```
>>> n = 100
>>> s = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((n,n),dtype=int)
>>> s[10, 12] = 1
>>> (10, 12) in get_items(s)
True
```

Note that for other types of sparse matrices, 0 can be expicetely set:

```
>>> s = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((n,n),dtype=int)
>>> s[12, 14] = 0
>>> (12, 14) in get_items(s)
True
```

Comment: I don't recommend depending on the 'explicit zero' functionality across Scipy versions, particularly in lines like `s[12, 14] = 0`. To my knowledge it is not a tested API feature.